Find regex pattern and use it in the next set of repeating lines until another like it replaces it
I'd like to find a pattern that rapeats every few sets of the second where I'd like to move it to.
The only example I could think of right now is a file listing; but I've needed this so many times. Usually I do column/block/vertical editing on an IDE or sometimes a bash script even, but I wonder if it can be done with regex substitution.

Sidenote: I know Python is great for this, BTW, but I'm great at not knowing Python. awk seems like it could do it too, but all I've managed to learn from the manpages is | awk '{print $<field#>}' and that's it. It's not even stdin-centric, but specifying a file needs its own PhD so I be pipin', hashtag growl.

# example: recursive ls (minus stuff)
# match >directoryName, insert++ it in file lines after >size, before >name
# throw away everything else ↙︎↙︎↙︎ line 1 below current line ↙︎↙︎↙︎
./ab204:
total 17316920
    16K  ./
    16K Jun 18  2024 ../
    69K  acm-nct04.xml
    43K  acm-nct05.xml
./ab205:
total 17316920
    16K  ./
    16K Jun 18  2024 ../
    69K  acm-vcv22.xml
    66K  acm-vcv25.xml
./ab206:
total 17316920
    16K  ./
    16K Jun 18  2024 ../
    69K  acm-zxv01.xml
    43K  acm-zxv02.xml

#
#
# desired output:
    69K ab204 acm-nct04.xml
    43K ab204 acm-nct05.xml
    69K ab205 acm-vcv22.xml
    66K ab205 acm-vcv25.xml
    69K ab204 acm-zxv01.xml
    43K ab204 acm-zxv02.xml


Using  (^\.\/(\w{2}\d+):\ntotal\s\d+\n.*\.\/\n.*\.{2}\/)(\s*\d+\w\s)(\s+.*ml\n) matches all of it— Sort of, capture group 2 is the directory name. Capture group 1 is everything from line 1 to and including line 4 (the one that ends in ../). Groups 3 and 4 are the size column and filename column respectively of line 5. Can easily be repeated to match subsequent lines by enclosing it, i.e: "(<group3><group4>)+".
Groups breakdown:
1     2                                          
(^\.\/(\w{2}\d+):\ntotal\s\d+\n.*\.\/\n.*\.{2}\/)…

 3           4
…(\s*\d+\w\s)(\s+.*ml\n)

The enclosure of groups 3,4 would become the new group 3, while former groups 3,4 would be pushed ➞ to become 4,5. Correct?
1     2                                          
(^\.\/(\w{2}\d+):\ntotal\s\d+\n.*\.\/\n.*\.{2}\/)…

 34           5
…((\s*\d+\w\s)(\s+.*ml\n))+

I got all the pieces, I think, what I cannot figure out is how to replace in a repeating pattern. I'd have to do something like:
$4$2$5      # (VSCode)

Or rather, capture groups inside another repeating capture group, and I have no idea how to repeat them one after the other on their own. $2 inside of $3. …maybe if $1 were part of $3 but also optional (…)??— IDK! I'm too stupid.
Plus, y'know… I still have to find the upcoming $2 on the next set. It seems like repeating the whole thing could do it, but one thing at a time, I guess. Can regex solve this or is it the wrong tool?

Again a regex question without a mention of app where you want to use it. SuperUser is about software related problems, not random out of context regex questions.
